# ActiveMQ - Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml]

Tags: java, mysql, xml, activemq-classic, kahadb

After of implement the persistence with "MySQL" (http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-support.html)

I'm find the next problem:

---

File config: --> activemq.xml

---

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <!-- <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/> -->
            <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="10 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="5 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!-- MySql DataSource Setup -->
    <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
     destroy-method="close">
         <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/activemq?relaxAutoCommit=true"/>
         <property name="username" value="user"/>
         <property name="password" value="pass"/>
         <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

---

File: --> activemq.log

---

```
2015-12-15 17:34:31,411 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@d799e8: startup date [Tue Dec 15 17:34:31 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2015-12-15 17:34:32,813 | WARN  | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#13fdf13' of type [org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter] while setting bean property 'persistenceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#13fdf13' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysql-ds' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'mysql-ds' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)[spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)[spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-3.18.jar:3.18]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-3.18.jar:3.18]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.12.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)[wrapper.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
2015-12-15 17:34:32,933 | ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#13fdf13' of type [org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter] while setting bean property 'persistenceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#13fdf13' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysql-ds' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'mysql-ds' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory | WrapperSimpleAppMain
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#13fdf13' of type [org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter] while setting bean property 'persistenceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#13fdf13' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysql-ds' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'mysql-ds' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)[spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)[spring-context-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-3.18.jar:3.18]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-3.18.jar:3.18]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:62)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.12.1.jar:5.12.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.12.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.12.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)[wrapper.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_65]
```

---

Could you please help me fixing this problem?

Answer (score 5):

ActiveMQ `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

Have a look in your activemq/lib/optional folder. If you have commons-dbcp2 jar instead of commons-dbcp, change the bean of your datasource class from

`<bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"`

to

`<bean id="oracle-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"`

Bit annoying that on the ActiveMQ site it's JDBC example is still using the old class

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`
which causes:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
```

You are missing following jar in your class path: commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar

You can download it from here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi